# herencia múltiple en java sin repetir código

Tags: java, herencia

tengo una duda sobre un trabajo, tengo que hacer tres clases: `producto`, `contenedor` y `camión`.

Dentro del `contenedor` se pueden meter `productos` y otros contenedores, y dentro del `camion`: productos y contenedores.

Pues bien, yo en java lo he implementado mediante una clase padre llamada `almacen` que deriva en `contenedor` y `camion`, y una interfaz llamada `almacenable` que se implementa en `contenedor` y `camion`.

La clase `almacenable` tiene una funcion guardar que recibe como parametro una interfaz `almacenable` y en ella es necesario saber el volumen de lo que se va a almacenar.

Queria saber si hay alguna manera de hacer una funcion volumen para las clases `contenedor` y `producto` pero implementarla solo una vez. os paso el codigo aqui:

```
class Producto implements almacenable{
    private String nombre;
    public double volumen;

    public Producto(double volumen, String nombre){
            this.volumen=volumen;
            this.nombre=nombre;
        }
        public double volumen(){ return this.volumen;}
};

interface almacenable{
    public double volumen();
}

class almacen{
    private double capacidad;
    public almacen(double volumen){
            this.capacidad=volumen;
        }
};

class Contenedor extends almacen implements almacenable
{       private double volumen;
        public Contenedor(double volumen){
            super(volumen);
            this.volumen=volumen;
        }
        public double volumen(){ return this.volumen;}
};

class Camion extends almacen
{
    public Camion(double volumen){
            super(volumen);
        }
};
```

Como veis he tenido que implementar la funcion volumen tanto en contenedor como en producto, habría alguna manera de implementarla una sola vez, tal como he hecho con la funcion guardar?

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo usar el [Patrón de diseño composite](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_(patr%C3%B3n_de_dise%C3%B1o)) para el problema que tratas de resolver.
Yo pondría la siguiente jerarquía de herencia:

```
Interfaz ContenedorGenerico
Clase Almacen implementa ContenedorGenerico (Porque un almacen es un ContenedorGenerico)
Clase Camion implementa ContenedorGenerico (un camion es un ContenedorGenerico)
Clase Contenedor implementa ContenedorGenerico (un contenedor es un ContenedorGenerico)
Clase ContenedorDeContenedores implementa ContenedorGenerico (Esta si fuera el caso)
```

Y aunque la función del calculo del `volumen` estaría en `ContenedorGenerico` no se haría ahí la implementación sino en cada una de las clases.

Imagina una clase `Figura` con un método `perimetro` y de ella heredan `Circulo` y `Cuadrado`. La implementación de `perimetro` debe ser distinta en ambas, lo cual creo que es tu caso para el volumen.

Y se me olvidaba, esto no se llama **herencia multiple**, esto no existe en java. Yo hubiera puesto "**mi jerarquia de herencia**"

Comment: El enlace del patrón de diseño está roto :(

Comment: Según este diseño, un `Camion` puede almacenar otros `Camion`es.

Comment: Ya corregi el link. Y si un Camion, digamos un Trailer enorme puede llevar dentro tal vez unos dos camionsitos, que almacenan producto. Igual que una bodega o almacen puede tener varios trailers o camiones. Ya depende del caso especifico hacer restricciones o no. Recuerden son "patrones de diseño" y no siempre se deben/pueden seguir al 100%, por que tienes que adaptar el patron a tu caso particular.

Comment: Comprendo tu idea, pero las restricciones están descritas en el problema y el diseño debe cumplir con eso. Además, OP ya está utilizando el patrón Composite de alguna manera, pero a nivel de `Producto` y `Contenedor` a través de la interfaz `Almacenable`.

Comment: Eso requiere mas analisis, y ya di mi posible solucion. No puedo hacer el sistema entero yo y pegarlo ahi con esa cantidad de informacion. Le comente del patrón porque me parece que no lo conocia, y el conocerlo le puede dar ideas de como hacer la implementación, ya que al estar haciendo esta persona el desarrollo obvio tiene mas información sobre el sistema a desarrollar.

Answer (score 1):

El problema que tienes es que estás repitiendo la implementación del método `getVolumen` en las clases `Producto` y `Contenedor` y quieres evitar eso puesto que es "lo mismo" y:

- `Producto` no puede extender de `Almacen` donde ya se tiene `volumen` porque esto haría que `Producto` pueda almacenar instancias de `Producto` y `Contenedor` y eso está prohibido.
- `Contenedor` ya extiende de `Almacen`, por tanto no puede extender de otra clase para ser un `Almacenable`.

Por esto dices que tu problema es de múltiple herencia (o eso creo).

---

He llegado a un diseño donde puedes resolver estos problemas pero requiere agregar una interfaz y una clase más. Esta es mi propuesta:

```
/**
 * Interfaz que define que un objeto tiene volumen
 */
interface Volumetrico {
    double getVolumen();
}
/**
 * Clase abstracta que implementa Volumetrico.
 * Define el atributo volumen y cómo obtenerlo.
 */
abstract class Objeto3d implements Volumetrico {
    protected double volumen;
    public Objeto3d(double volumen) {
        this.volumen = volumen;
    }
    public double getVolumen() {
        return volumen;
    }
}
/**
 * Interfaz que define que un elemento se puede almacenar
 * y que el objeto es Volumetrico
 */
interface Almacenable extends Volumetrico {
}
/**
 * Clase que posee volumen (extendiendo de Objeto3d) y
 * que puede coleccionar Almacenables.
 */
abstract class Almacen extends Objeto3d {
    protected List<Almacenable> almacenables;
    public Almacen(double volumen) {
        super(volumen);
        this.almacenables = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    public boolean agregar(Almacenable almacenable) {
        almacenables.add(almacenable);
        return true;
    }
}
/**
 * El Producto es un Objeto3d (tiene volumen)
 * que implementa Almacenable (se puede almacenar en un Almacen).
 */
class Producto extends Objeto3d implements Almacenable {
    public Producto(double volumen) {
        super(volumen);
    }
}
/**
 * El Contenedor es un Almacen, es decir es un Objeto3d (tiene volumen)
 * que puede almacenar Almacenables.
 * Asimismo, puede ser Almacenable.
 */
class Contenedor extends Almacen implements Almacenable {
    public Contenedor(double volumen) {
        super(volumen);
    }
}
/**
 * El Camion solo es un Almacen, es decir es un Objeto3d que
 * puede almacenar Almacenables
 */
class Camion extends Almacen {
    public Camion(double volumen) {
        super(volumen);
    }
}
```

Este diseño "ahorra" la re-definición y re-implementación de métodos a lo largo de las clases, que es lo que buscabas. Aquí un código de ejemplo que muestra que el código funciona:

```
Camion camion = new Camion(50d);
Contenedor contenedor1 = new Contenedor(25d);
Contenedor contenedor2 = new Contenedor(20d);
Contenedor contenedor3 = new Contenedor(15d);
Producto producto1 = new Producto(10d);
Producto producto2 = new Producto(5d);
Producto producto3 = new Producto(5d);
Producto producto4 = new Producto(25d);
Producto producto5 = new Producto(5d);

contenedor3.agregar(producto1);
contenedor3.agregar(producto2);
contenedor2.agregar(contenedor3);
contenedor2.agregar(producto3);
contenedor1.agregar(producto4);

camion.agregar(contenedor2);
camion.agregar(contenedor1);
camion.agregar(producto5);

Camion camionX = new Camion(100d);
//error de compilacion
camionX.agregar(camion);
```

El problema con diseños como este es que son muy frágiles cuando se deben realizar cambios. Diseños como este no los recomiendo en el mundo real.

Comment: Está muy bien, lo único que has eliminado el valor ´capacidad´ que es lo que determina lo que puede caber en cada contenedor o camión, en este caso camión solo tendría capacidad que sería la variable que se iría decrementando al añadir objetos, es decir, no hace falta una arrayList infinita, ya que todos contenedor y camion tiene una capacidad definida, que en el caso del contenedor el volumen es igual a su capacidad, y no hace falta saber que objetos hay dentro. Pero muchas gracias

Comment: Al leer el problema dice: "Dentro del contenedor se pueden meter productos y otros contenedores, y dentro del camion: productos y contenedores." Si eso no significa que deben haber listas para poder **meter** cosas dentro de estas clases, el diseño que tienes ya soporta lo que pides y la verdad no entiendo tu problema.

Answer (score 0):

Mi solución, muy similar a las anteriores:

```
public interface DatosProducto {
  public double getPeso();
  public double getVolumen();

}
```

Jerarquía de objetos Producto:

```
public abstract class Producto implements DatosProducto {
  private int id;
  private String nombre;

  public Producto(int id, String nombre) {
    this.id=id;
    this.nombre=nombre;
  }
  public int getId() {
    return id;
  }
  public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
  }
  public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
  }
  public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
  }

}

public class ProductoA extends Producto {

  public ProductoA() {
    super(1, "ProductoA");
  }

  @Override
  public double getPeso() {
    return 10;
  }

  @Override
  public double getVolumen() {
    return 2.2;
  }

}

public class ProductoB extends Producto {

  public ProductoB() {
    super(2, "ProductoB");
  }

  @Override
  public double getPeso() {
    return 17;
  }

  @Override
  public double getVolumen() {
    return 3.5;
  }

}
```

Clase composite para los diferentes tipos de contenedores:

```
public class ContenedorComposite implements DatosProducto {

  private List<DatosProducto> listaDatosProducto;

  public ContenedorComposite() {
    listaDatosProducto=new ArrayList<DatosProducto>();
  }

  public void addDatosProducto(DatosProducto datosProducto) {
    listaDatosProducto.add(datosProducto);
  }

  @Override
  public double getPeso() {
    int pesoTotal=0;
    for(DatosProducto datosProducto: listaDatosProducto) {
        pesoTotal += datosProducto.getPeso();
    }
    return pesoTotal;
  }

  @Override
  public double getVolumen() {
    int volumenTotal=0;
    for(DatosProducto datosProducto: listaDatosProducto) {
        volumenTotal += datosProducto.getVolumen();
    }
    return volumenTotal;
  }

}
```

Jerarquía de contenedores:

```
public class CamionContenedor extends ContenedorComposite {

  private static final int MAXIMO_VOLUMEN=3000;

  public int getVolumenMaximo() {
    return MAXIMO_VOLUMEN;
  }

}

public class Contenedor extends ContenedorComposite {

  private static final int MAXIMA_CAPACIDAD=10;

  public int getCapacidad() {
    return MAXIMA_CAPACIDAD;
  }

}
```

Test para verificar su uso:

```
public class ContenedorCompositeTest {

  @Test
  public void test() {
    ContenedorComposite composite=new ContenedorComposite();

    CamionContenedor camion1=new CamionContenedor();
    camion1.addDatosProducto(new ProductoA());
    camion1.addDatosProducto(new ProductoB());
    assertThat(camion1.getPeso(),is(27.0));

    CamionContenedor camion2=new CamionContenedor();
    camion2.addDatosProducto(new ProductoA());
    camion2.addDatosProducto(new ProductoB());
    assertThat(camion2.getPeso(),is(27.0));

    Contenedor contenedor1=new Contenedor();
    contenedor1.addDatosProducto(new ProductoA());
    assertThat(contenedor1.getPeso(),is(10.0));

    Contenedor contenedor2=new Contenedor();
    contenedor2.addDatosProducto(new ProductoB());
    assertThat(contenedor2.getPeso(),is(17.0));

    camion1.addDatosProducto(contenedor1);
    camion2.addDatosProducto(contenedor2);
    composite.addDatosProducto(camion1);
    composite.addDatosProducto(camion2);
    assertThat(composite.getPeso(),is(81.0));

  }

}
```